# Error in Running Docker image. Showing no module named cv2,request,boto3

Tags: python, opencv, docker, dockerfile, boto3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from time import sleep
import datetime
import os
import shutil
import cv2
import io
import numpy as np
import glob
from threading import Thread
import urllib2
import requests
import json
import boto3
import datetime
```

I am not able to run my script on docker as I am not able to run modules like `cv2`,`numpy`, `requests` and `boto3`. It works perfectly when I run it on terminal but when I run it as docker image it is showing error that no modules named ... How can i make it run on my docker?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM resin/raspberry-pi-python:latest
RUN mkdir /myscript
WORKDIR /myscript
COPY capturing.py .
CMD ["/myscript/capturing.py", "-flag"]
```

Comment: Show your `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run your container:

```
docker run -it <image_name>
```

and execute the following command in python console that will install specified packages in your container:

```
import os
os.system("pip install --upgrade pip")
os.system("pip install numpy requests boto3 opencv-python")
```

You will see:

```
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.13.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (17.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 17.0MB 124kB/s 
Collecting requests
  Downloading requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 4.8MB/s 
Collecting boto3
  Downloading boto3-1.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (128kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 3.4MB/s 
Collecting opencv-python
  Downloading opencv_python-3.3.0.10-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (15.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 15.5MB 126kB/s 
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Downloading certifi-2017.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (330kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 337kB 2.9MB/s 
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 4.4MB/s 
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Downloading idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 6.0MB/s 
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Downloading urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl (132kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 3.4MB/s 
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from boto3)
  Downloading jmespath-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 (from boto3)
  Downloading s3transfer-0.1.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 6.4MB/s 
Collecting botocore<1.8.0,>=1.7.0 (from boto3)
  Downloading botocore-1.7.46-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.7MB 535kB/s 
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore<1.8.0,>=1.7.0->boto3)
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 3.1MB/s 
Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from botocore<1.8.0,>=1.7.0->boto3)
  Downloading docutils-0.14-py3-none-any.whl (543kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 552kB 2.2MB/s 
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.8.0,>=1.7.0->boto3)
  Downloading six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy, certifi, chardet, idna, urllib3, requests, jmespath, six, python-dateutil, docutils, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, opencv-python
Successfully installed boto3-1.4.7 botocore-1.7.46 certifi-2017.11.5 chardet-3.0.4 docutils-0.14 idna-2.6 jmespath-0.9.3 numpy-1.13.3 opencv-python-3.3.0.10 python-dateutil-2.6.1 requests-2.18.4 s3transfer-0.1.11 six-1.11.0 urllib3-1.22
```

So all is ok. I tested it in container built using `FROM python:latest` Dockerfile.

Comment: Don't forget the opencv module as well (`pip install opencv-python` usually works fine)

Comment: @Pulkit if it helped - please consider my post as an answer

Comment: yes i am having issue in installing opencv. What command should i give to docker file for open-cv.

Comment: `pip install opencv-python` should work as well as `pip3 install opencv-python` if you use `python3`, so dockerfile should contain for python2.7 `RUN pip install numpy requests boto3 opencv-python`. Did you rebuild your image after editing dockerfile?

Comment: i am getting this  error :  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python

Comment: When I'm trying to run container from `resin/raspberry-pi-python` image - I'm receiving these errors: `panic: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error" [recovered]
 panic: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"
`
Looks like it's something wrong with the image

Comment: Yes its because of architecture. You can try FROM python:latest. Hope this will work perfect on your device.

Comment: try  `FROM python:latest`

Comment: Got it. See UPD in my answer.

Comment: i already imported all these modules in my terminal. what change should i make in my docker file and where i have to import the above modules ? in Docker file or in terminal?

Comment: @ArtsiomPraneuski i got it it is downloading. I will tell u after successful execution of my file.

Comment: i am not able to install opencv in my script. Getting this error :  
`     Collecting opencv-python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myscript/capturing.py", line 11, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2`

Comment: Hmm, maybe there is no such package "No matching distribution found for opencv-python" for this arch (I suppose you have ARM cpu on your Raspberry)... That's odd

Comment: Yes, i have ARM CPU on mr Rpi. so, what should i do to make it run?